# How can I force display the keyboard in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How can I force display the virtual keyboard in landscape mode in startup of the activity? and this keyboard doesn't fill the entire screen so I can display some views above the keyboard.

Comment: "and this keyboard doesn't fill the entire screen so I can display some views above the keyboard." -- you do not have control over this, sorry.

Comment: Why? I can see this exact behavior in default browser in my phone.

Comment: There is no guarantee that all IMEs on all devices will support `flagNoFullscreen`. Do not design an application that assumes that `flagNoFullscreen` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking to force to show the soft keyboard in landscape mode in a device with hard keyboard, right?

We can do this by following code:

```
InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(input != null)
    input.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer at a similar question here:
[How to open only half keyboard in Landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648401/how-to-open-only-half-keyboard-in-landscape-mode/10614766#10614766)

For the solution.

You'll need to introduce an attribute of `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` into your xml to produce the effect you seek.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only combination that worked for me:

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null && imm != null) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

and to show it:

```
private void showKeyboard(View view){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    }
}
```

I also added `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to the view in XML.

Comment: WOW! I asked that question 7 years ago. I'm no longer an Android developer :D

Comment: The answer is also for other users with the same question ;-)

Comment: yes for sure, you just reminded me of old times where I thought I would be an android developer and now I'm an iOS developer instead :D